# Running many Asynctask on timer(countdowntimer)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, countdowntimer

I have created a `CountDownTimer` like this

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        //timeout
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
         PaymentAsyncTask paymentTask = new PaymentAsyncTask(this);
         paymentTask.execute();

        }
}
```

in `onPostExecute` of `paymentTask`, i am doing some operations on some specific condition.

Basically, i am checking from some website, after some time interval(say 3 second), task has been completed or not.

**Now if internet runs fast, there is no issue with this code,**

**if task gets completed,i cancel the timer in onPostExecute and do my further work.**

But if internet runs **slow**, which means response doesn't come in 3 seconds,
`onPostExecute` is called more than once(**executing code inside it more than once**), while the task was already completed, its just that i got the response late due to server issue/internet delay.

How i can make sure that code inside `onPostExecute` gets called only once?

Possible approaches:

1. Take some static flag variable, make it true and check in others...

I am looking for some solution, which is reliable, maybe android provides some mechanism to **synchronise** this.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually check the status of the `AsyncTask` and depending on the current status you can perform logic.

Please take your `AsyncTask` object Globally in your `Activity` class.

Code Snippet:

```
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
    PaymentAsyncTask paymentTask = null;

      public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
      }

      @Override
      public void onFinish() {
        //timeout 
      }

      @Override
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
        if(paymentTask == null) {
            android.util.Log.i("TAG", "Null");
            paymentTask = new PaymentAsyncTask(this);
            paymentTask.execute();
        } else {
            //Depending on your situation take appropriate action
            android.util.Log.i("TAG", "Not Null");
            if(paymentTask.getStatus() == (AsyncTask.Status.PENDING)) {
                //Indicates that the task has not been executed yet.
                android.util.Log.i("TAG", "Pending");
            } else if(paymentTask.getStatus() == (AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)) {
                //Indicates that the task is running.
                android.util.Log.i("TAG", "Running");
            } else if(paymentTask.getStatus() == (AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)) {
                //Indicates that AsyncTask.onPostExecute has finished.
                android.util.Log.i("TAG", "Finished");
            } 
        }
      }
}
```

I hope this can help you out.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation..my question is exactly this, if on next call of onTick(), my previous task is pending/running due to network delay, in this case, i can not execute it because its already pending/running.
Suppose i start my task at 'x=3' second, onTick will be called again at 'x=6', and my task started at x=3 is still pending at x=6..but i need to get fresh status at x=6, so i need to start the tasks at each x=3n. its just that when one of them return me 'ok' response, i want all other tasks started after its time to say..ABORT!!!

Comment: i want to start each task at x=3n, but when one of them started at x=t return 'ok', i do not want to execute code written inside onPostExecute of all other tasks started after this x=t, bit lengthy but i hope you got my point..

Comment: @Sunny Depending on the status you can cancel the current task and start a new task or you can continue with your running task.

Comment: as per my requirement, i should start new task on each onTick, otherwise how will i get fresh status? so cancelling the task may not be a good idea, i am now taking one global boolean which i set to true whenever i get 'ok' response, and all the postExecute check for that global before executing further..

Answer (score 0):

please check its helpful for you as per http://daniel-codes.blogspot.in/...

**Is Your AsyncTask Running?**

A short note about AsyncTask: Prior to 4.0 (and maybe prior to 3.0, but I haven't tested), **AsyncTask.getStatus()** might lie to you. If the AsyncTask is canceled, it won't set the status correctly; instead, it will remain RUNNING far after **AsyncTask.onCancelled()** finishes.

My initial thought was to use **AsyncTask.isCancelled()**, but you can run into some concurrency issues there if you're trying to gauge whether the AsyncTask is done from another thread.  A cancelled AsyncTask doesn't necessarily end the moment you cancel it; in fact, if you're not checking **isCancelled()** regularly in **doInBackground()** then you can end up having the AsyncTask run for a while after you cancel.

My solution is to set a boolean at the end of **onCancelled()** that will indicate to the system that you got to the end of execution.  Here's an example of writing an AsyncTask where you can properly know when it's been finished:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask {
  private boolean mFinishedCancel = false;

  protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    return null; // You'd normally do something here
  }

  protected void onCancelled() {
    mFinishedCancel = true;
  }

  public boolean isFinished() {
    return getStatus() == Status.FINISHED || mFinishedCancel;
  }
}
```

Comment: it means taking a flag when needed is not a bad idea..let me check this approach...
As i mentioned in first approach, taking a flag would help, but i was just thinking if i can just avoid playing with flags, because this is related to payment...i don't want any bug in this in real time complex scenario..rigorous testing would help the cause i think..:)